# Relative path to a folder works when run locally but not on a server

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have a spring boot project which uses thymeleaf for UI. 
My static content are under project/src/main/resources/static folder and templates are under project/src/main/templates folder.

In my application.properties I am referring to these folders like

```
spring.resources.static-locations=classpath:/static/
spring.thymeleaf.prefix=classpath:/templates/
```

This is working perfectly fine in my local.
But when I deploy it to the EC2 instance It's throwing the below error -

> Exception processing template "/login": Error resolving template [/login], template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers

which essentially means that this folder is accessible when running in my local but after containerizing and deploying the app, this way of accessing the folders isn't working.

I have tried to look this up, but there are ways to refer to a file under resources relatively but not the entire folders.

Please let me know what I am missing here.

Answer (score 0):

How are you containerizing?
Can you move your templates inside the src/main/resources directory? Everything in this directory should be statically available.

Comment: I am containerizing using Docker. The problem is I have a large number of .html files under templates , similarly large number of files under static. All properly categorized and sorted. If I remove all of them from their respective categorized folders and dump them under resources it's going to be a mess I think. Can you suggest any other alternatives?